# My Sprites are not showing properly in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, display, pygame-surface

My sprites aren't showing properly in my program. The map displays fine, but the sprite only shows for a split second when I quit the program by pressing the big X at the top right (But not when I exit by pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd>)

Display sprites code:

```
# Protagonist Sprites
protagR = [pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/JoArrow_R1_1.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/JoArrow_R1_2.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/JoArrow_R1_3.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/JoArrow_R1_2.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/JoArrow_R1_1.png")]
protagL = [pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/JoArrow_L1_1.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/JoArrow_L1_2.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/JoArrow_L1_3.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/JoArrow_L1_2.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/JoArrow_L1_1.png")]
protagU = [pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/JoArrow_U1_1.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/JoArrow_U1_2.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/JoArrow_U1_3.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/JoArrow_U1_2.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/JoArrow_U1_1.png")]
protagD = [pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/JoArrow_D1_1.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/JoArrow_D1_2.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/JoArrow_D1_3.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/JoArrow_D1_2.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/JoArrow_D1_1.png")]
# Bullet Sprites
bulletsP = [pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/Bullet_1.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/Bullet_2.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/Bullet_3.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/Bullet_4.png")]
bulletsE = [pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/E_Bullet_1.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/E_Bullet_2.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/E_Bullet_3.png")]
# Enemy Sprites
enemyR = [pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/Enemy_R1_1.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/Enemy_R1_2.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/Enemy_R1_3.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/Enemy_R1_4.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/Enemy_R1_5.png")]
enemyL = [pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/Enemy_L1_1.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/Enemy_L1_2.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/Enemy_L1_3.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/Enemy_L1_4.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/Enemy_L1_5.png")]
enemyU = [pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/Enemy_U1_1.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/Enemy_U1_2.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/Enemy_U1_3.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/Enemy_U1_4.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/Enemy_U1_5.png")]
enemyD = [pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/Enemy_D1_1.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/Enemy_D1_2.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/Enemy_D1_3.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/Enemy_D1_4.png"), pygame.image.load("ASG2_Graphics/Enemy_D1_5.png")]
```

Class code:

```
class player():
        def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, walkCount):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.width = width
            self.height = height
            self.vel = 5
            self.up = False
            self.down = False
            self.left = False
            self.right = False
            self.up = False
            self.down = False
            self.walkCount = walkCount

        def redrawGameWindow(self, window):
            dest = (self.x, self.y)
            if self.walkCount + 1 >= 30:
                self.walkCount = 0
            if self.left:
                window.blit(protagL[self.walkCount//3], dest)
                self.walkCount += 1
            elif self.right:
                window.blit(protagR[self.walkCount//3], dest)
                self.walkCount += 1
            elif self.up:
                window.blit(protagU[self.walkCount//3], dest)
                self.walkCount += 1
            elif self.down:
                window.blit(protagD[self.walkCount//3], dest)
                self.walkCount += 1
            else:
                window.blit(protagL[self.walkCount//3], dest)
            pygame.display.update()
```

Map displaying code:

```
def multilineRender(screen, text, x, y, the_font, colour=(0, 0, 0), justification="left"):
    justification = justification[0].upper()
    # text = text.strip().replace('\r','').split('\n')
    max_width = 0
    text_bitmaps = []
    # Convert all the text into bitmaps, calculate the justification width
    for char in text:
        text_bitmap = the_font.render(char, True, colour)
        text_width = text_bitmap.get_width()
        text_bitmaps.append((text_width, text_bitmap))
        if (max_width < text_width):
            max_width = text_width
    # Paint all the text bitmaps to the screen with justification
    for (width, bitmap) in text_bitmaps:
        xPos = x
        width_diff = max_width - width
        if justification == 'R':  # right-justify
            xPos = x + width_diff
        elif justification == 'C':  # centre-justify
            xPos = x + (width_diff // 2)

        screen.blit(bitmap, (xPos, y))
        y += bitmap.get_height()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Character Displaying Code:

```
def movePlayer(board):
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(15)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        arrowKeys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if arrowKeys[pygame.K_LEFT] and board.x > 25 + board.vel:
            board.x -= board.vel
            board.left = True
            board.right = False
            board.up = False
            board.down = False
        elif arrowKeys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and board.x < 510 - board.width - board.vel:
            board.x += board.vel
            board.right = True
            board.left = False
            board.up = False
            board.down = False
        elif arrowKeys[pygame.K_UP] and board.y > 40 + board.vel:
            board.y -= board.vel
            board.right = False
            board.left = False
            board.up = True
            board.down = False
        elif arrowKeys[pygame.K_DOWN] and board.y < 450 - board.height - board.vel:
            board.y += board.vel
            board.right = False
            board.left = False
            board.up = False
            board.down = True
        elif arrowKeys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:  # ESC key
            stopGame()
        else:
            board.right = False
            board.left = False
            board.up = False
            board.down = False
            board.walkCount = 0

    board.redrawGameWindow(window)
    pygame.display.quit()
```

Main code:

```
def main():
    inFile = open("map(TEST).txt", "r")
    text = inFile.read().splitlines()  # splitlines is to exclude the '\n'
    inFile.close()
    window.fill((0, 0, 0))

    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Calibri", 35)

    window.fill((0,0,0))
    board = player(30, 45, 64, 64, 0)
    multilineRender(window, text, 20, 20, myfont, (255, 255, 255))

    while True:
        # movePlayer(board)
        multilineRender(window, text, 20, 20, myfont, (255, 255, 255))
        movePlayer(board)
```

I should also mention that when I quit the program, i get this error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Python_Projects/Asg2/m5_PYGAME_STYLE.py", line 156, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Python_Projects/Asg2/m5_PYGAME_STYLE.py", line 153, in main
>     multilineRender(window, text, 20, 20, myfont, (255, 255, 255))
>   File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Python_Projects/Asg2/m5_PYGAME_STYLE.py", line 83, in multilineRender
>     screen.blit(bitmap, (xPos, y))
> pygame.error: display Surface quit
> ```

...but I doubt it's related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `pygame.display.quit()` form `movePlayer` And turn the `while` loop in `movePlayer` to an selection `if`. Note, you have a loop in `main`, so use it.
Further more, I recommend to do `pygame.display.update()` in main.

The main application loop has to:

- handle the events and update the objects dependent on the input events.
- clear the display
- draw the scene
- update the display

```py
def main():
    inFile = open("map(TEST).txt", "r")
    text = inFile.read().splitlines()  # splitlines is to exclude the '\n'
    inFile.close()
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Calibri", 35)

    board = player(30, 45, 64, 64, 0)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(15)

        # clear the display
        window.fill((0, 0, 0))

        # draw the scene
        board.redrawGameWindow(window)
        multilineRender(window, text, 20, 20, myfont, (255, 255, 255))

        # update the display 
        pygame.display.update()

        # handle the events and update the objects
        run = movePlayer(board)
```

`movePlayer` has to return `true` is the game is still running and else `false`:

```py
def movePlayer(board):

    run = True
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    arrowKeys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if arrowKeys[pygame.K_LEFT] and board.x > 25 + board.vel:
        board.x -= board.vel
        board.left, board.right, board.up, board.down = True, False, False, False
    elif arrowKeys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and board.x < 510 - board.width - board.vel:
        board.x += board.vel
        board.left, board.right, board.up, board.down = False, True, False, False
    elif arrowKeys[pygame.K_UP] and board.y > 40 + board.vel:
        board.y -= board.vel
        board.left, board.right, board.up, board.down = False, False, True, False
    elif arrowKeys[pygame.K_DOWN] and board.y < 450 - board.height - board.vel:
        board.y += board.vel
        board.left, board.right, board.up, board.down = False, False, False, True
    elif arrowKeys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:  # ESC key
        stopGame()
    else:
        board.left, board.right, board.up, board.down = False, False, False, False
        board.walkCount = 0

    return run
```

`multilineRender` does no `pygame.display.update()`:

```py
def multilineRender(screen, text, x, y, the_font, colour=(0, 0, 0), justification="left"):
    justification = justification[0].upper()
    # text = text.strip().replace('\r','').split('\n')
    max_width = 0
    text_bitmaps = []
    # Convert all the text into bitmaps, calculate the justification width
    for char in text:
        text_bitmap = the_font.render(char, True, colour)
        text_width = text_bitmap.get_width()
        text_bitmaps.append((text_width, text_bitmap))
        if (max_width < text_width):
            max_width = text_width
    # Paint all the text bitmaps to the screen with justification
    for (width, bitmap) in text_bitmaps:
        xPos = x
        width_diff = max_width - width
        if justification == 'R':  # right-justify
            xPos = x + width_diff
        elif justification == 'C':  # centre-justify
            xPos = x + (width_diff // 2)

        screen.blit(bitmap, (xPos, y))
        y += bitmap.get_height()
```